# C program to print out LCD digital numbers from an array

Tags: c, arrays, lcd

Sorry if this is duplicate question. But this time I want to make my question clear and how I want my output to be. I'm given a project to create a C program to print out LCD digital display numbers from a list of arrays, which will be outputted in a text file. I'm a rookie at this and I hope you can help me. Instead of the normal 7-elements LCD display, it should be printed with 12-elements, exactly as in this image:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
    #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

    #include <stdio.h>

    #define COL 12
    #define ROW 10

    int main(void)
    {
      int i, j;
      const int arr2 [ROW][COL] = {{1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1},   //0
                                {0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0},  //1
                                {1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0},  //2
                                {1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1},  //3
                                {0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1},  //4
                                {1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1},  //5
                                {1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1},  //6
                                {1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1},  //7
                                {1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1},  //8
                                {1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1}}; //9


    /* The print functions should go here. 
           If array = 1, it should print out either this: _ or |
           to print out the digital numbers.
           Else, if array = 0, it will print out nothing */
```

Here is the code of my attempt, but failed. I didn't finish the code because it didn't work correctly. I used if statements inside for loops. So I'm confused and I need your help.

```
for (i = 0; i < (sizeof(arr2)/sizeof(arr2[0][0])/COL); i++)
{
    if (arr2[i][0] == 1)
    {
        printf("| ");
    } else if (arr2[i][0] == 0)
    {
        printf("\t");
    }

    if (arr2[i][1] == 1)
    {
        printf("|");
    } else if (arr2[i][1] == 0)
    {
        printf("\t\n");
    }

    if (arr2[i][2] == 1)
    {
        printf("|");
    } else if (arr2[i][2] == 0)
    {
        printf("\t");
    }

    if (arr2[i][3] == 1)
    {
        printf("|");
    } else if (arr2[i][3] == 0)
    {
        printf("\t");
    }

    if (arr2[i][4] == 1)
    {
        printf("|");
    } else if (arr2[i][4] == 0)
    {
        printf("\t");
    }

    if (arr2[i][5] == 1)
    {
        printf("|");
    } else if (arr2[i][5] == 0)
    {
        printf("\t");
    }

    if (arr2[i][6] == 1)
    {
        printf("|");
    } else if (arr2[i][6] == 0)
    {
        printf("\t");
    }

    if (arr2[i][7] == 1)
    {
        printf("|");
    } else if (arr2[i][7] == 0)
    {
        printf("\t");
    }

    if (arr2[i][8] == 1)
    {
        printf("|");
    } else if (arr2[i][8] == 0)
    {
        printf("\t");
    }

    if (arr2[i][9] == 1)
    {
        printf("|");
    } else if (arr2[i][9] == 0)
    {
        printf("\t");
    }

    if (arr2[i][10] == 1)
    {
        printf("|");
    } else if (arr2[i][10] == 0)
    {
        printf("\t");
    }

    if (arr2[i][11] == 1)
    {
        printf("|");
    } else if (arr2[i][11] == 0)
    {
        printf("\t");
    }

    for (j = 0; j < (sizeof(arr2)/sizeof(arr2[0][0])/ROW); j++)
    {
        if (arr2[0][j] == 1)
        {
            printf("_");
        } else if (arr2[0][j] == 0)
        {
            printf("\t");
        }

        if (arr2[1][j] == 1)
        {
            printf("_");
        } else if (arr2[1][j] == 0)
        {
            printf("\t");
        }

        if (arr2[2][j] == 1)
        {
            printf("_");
        } else if (arr2[2][j] == 0)
        {
            printf("\t");
        }
    }


return 0;
    }
```

When compiled, it kept showing this:
[image: arrays error]
Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: I suggest experimenting directly with output to text file since the spaces aren't the same when writing to file and when writing on console.

Comment: Tip: You can use a `switch` statement instead of so many `if`s.

Comment: *"it didn't work correctly."* is not much of a description.  Did it compile?  Did it run?  Did it give incorrect output or crash?  DESCRIBE YOUR DIFFICULTY.

Comment: @abelenky Hello. I've compiled it and it didn't come out right. I've added an update with a screenshot. Please take a look at the update. Thanks!

Comment: I think your 2D array encoding which segments are 'lit' is wrong if your segment numbering scheme starts with segment 0 for the top left bar of the `0`, then 1 for the next, then 2 for the vertical bar on the second row of segments, then 3 for the middle (unlit) bar, and 4 for the right bar.  That requires the data to be `{ 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, …` but your data starts `{ 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, …`.  Of course, you might have a different segment numbering scheme in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Each of the 12 segments is represented by either a `-` or a `|`; you should have an array (string?) that identifies the correct character to print when the segment is 'lit'.  When a segment is not lit, you should print a blank instead of a tab.  Your array name (`arr2`) is not all that informative.

Superficially, the code might be something along these lines:

```
char segment[] = "--|||--|||--";

for (int digit = 0; digit < 10; digit++)
{
    for (int segnum = 0; segnum < 12; segnum++)
    {
         if (arr2[digit][segnum] == 1)
             putchar(segment[segnum]);
         else
             putchar(' ');
         if (segnum == 1 || segnum == 4 || segnum == 6 || segnum == 9 || segnum == 11)
             putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

There are other, probably better, ways of encoding when a newline is required.  If you find yourself writing almost the same code over and over (as in the `if (segnum == 1 …)` line on the small scale, or in your printing code on a larger scale), then you're probably doing it wrong.

However, if you look at the digit 0, 1 and 2 carefully, you find that each is a 5x5 matrix of print positions (where I'm using `x` to emphasize points that need to be handled).  The last character on the top shows where the 12 segments are; the x's here will always be blanks (under my presentation scheme, which isn't definitively what you want).

```
x-x-x    xxxxx    x-x-x               x-x-x
|xxx|    xx|xx    xxxx|               |x|x|
xxxxx    xxxxx    x-x-x               x-x-x
|xxx|    xx|xx    |xxxx               |x|x|
x-x-x    xxxxx    x-x-x               x-x-x

 - -               - -                 - - 
|   |      |          |               | | | 
                   - -                 - -  
|   |      |      |                   | | |
 - -               - -                 - -
```

Note that if you use `_` instead of `-`, you get weird effects.  In interpreting the 1, I've gone with two vertical segments.  You will have to define what output you want to get the result you want.

---

Workable code

This solution contains 5 arrays: a bug-fixed version of your data array, the string shown above for the glyphs to be displayed, two arrays identifying the positions (x, y) where the glyphs appear in the 5x5 grid, and a 5x5 matrix of characters that contains the displayed data. The display is set to all blanks, and then the code uses the other arrays to put the right character in the right place for the current digit. Normally, I'd use an array of structures instead of 3 arrays, but if you're just learning arrays, you probably haven't covered structures yet.

```
/* SO 24233419 - 12-segment LCD digits */
/* Assuming no structures - simplifying assignment to display[y][x] */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

enum { COL = 12 };

int main(void)
{
    const int lcd_segment[][COL] =
    {
        { 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1 }, // 0
        { 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 }, // 1
        { 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1 }, // 2
        { 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1 }, // 3
        { 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 }, // 4
        { 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1 }, // 5
        { 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1 }, // 6
        { 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 }, // 7
        { 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1 }, // 8
        { 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1 }, // 9
    };

    const char segment_c[] = "--|||--|||--";
    const char segment_x[] = { 1, 3, 0, 2, 4, 1, 3, 0, 2, 4, 1, 3 };
    const char segment_y[] = { 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4 };

    char display[5][5];

    for (int digit = 0; digit < 10; digit++)
    {
        memset(display, ' ', sizeof(display));
        for (int segnum = 0; segnum < 12; segnum++)
        {
            if (lcd_segment[digit][segnum] == 1)
            {
                int x = segment_x[segnum];
                int y = segment_y[segnum];
                display[y][x] = segment_c[segnum];
            }
        }
        for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
                putchar(display[y][x]);
            putchar('\n');
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
 - - 
|   |

|   |
 - - 

  |  

  |  

 - - 
    |
 - - 
|    
 - - 
 - - 
    |
 - - 
    |
 - - 

|   |
 - - 
    |

 - - 
|    
 - - 
    |
 - - 
 - - 
|    
 - - 
|   |
 - - 
 - - 
    |

    |

 - - 
|   |
 - - 
|   |
 - - 
 - - 
|   |
 - - 
    |
 - -
```

Comment: The idea is good, from my exp the size of a whitespace in .txt file is equal to 2 '-'. I'd use a string / char array to create an image for each number and then just print it when required, only issue is newline if he needs the numbers in order like on picture. Then it would be much easier to just create 2 arrays and to experiment with the lines to get those 2 sets of numbers.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your contribution. However, it didn't print out exactly like in the picture to form the digital numbers in the .txt file. Is it possible to add a new tab \t to make the lines form correctly?

Comment: @user2967179: no, it doesn't, but it is a step on the way.  You're going to have to define what you want to appear for each of the digits.  Until you've done that, the output cannot be made correct.

Comment: @Survaf93: yes, that might be a better way to represent the digits.  See the update(s).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler  Thanks. Can you please show me the complete codes to print out 0, 1, and 2 in the form of the digital numbers like in the picture? This way, I can use those as a reference to print out the remaining numbers.

Comment: @user2967179; If he show you you that then what will you learn from your assignment? He already gave you an idea to use a 5x5 matrix and the representation of digits as 12 segment display.

Comment: No: I think you need to work out how to do it.  There are various possibilities, and you need to decide on one to use.

Comment: @user2967179 I strongly advise you to play with the lines and spaces, it's way better way to learn this. First line of 0 is space,-,space,-,space. You figure out the rest

Comment: @haccks I understand what you're telling me, but I'm new to the arrays. This will help me for other assignments. If you can just show me how to just do one number, it would still help.

Comment: @user2967179; Yes. We can understand you are new to the programming. But this is the way how you could learn programming by messing your head around these small projects.

Comment: @haccks I respect what you just said, but the assignment is due tomorrow. What I'm afraid of is that I won't solve it in time and submit it before the due date.

Comment: @user2967179; I uploaded a code for [7-segment display](https://github.com/haccks/Solutions-of-C-Programming-A-modern-Approach-by-K.N-KING/blob/master/7-Segment%20Display). You can use/modify it to make 12-segment display. Hope you will do. Best of luck :).

Comment: @user2967179: My working solution (not shown) contains 5 arrays: a bug-fixed version of your data array, the string shown above for the glyphs to be displayed, two arrays identifying the positions (x, y) where the glyphs appear in the 5x5 grid, and a 5x5 matrix of characters that contains the displayed data. The display is set to all blanks, and then the code uses the other arrays to put the right character in the right place for the current digit. Normally, I'd use an array of structures instead of 3 arrays, but if you're just learning arrays, you probably haven't covered structures yet.